# HotChocolate not mapping models properly to type

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

Hotchocolate does not appear to have mapped one of my models properly.
I have this product search model:

```
public class ProductSearchResponseModel : ISearchResult<SimpleProductViewModel>
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<FacetModel>> Facets { get; set; }
    public bool HasMoreResults { get; set; }
    public long Total { get; set; }
    public List<SimpleProductViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there, it has a **FacetModel** which looks like this:

```
public class FacetModel
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public object From { get; set; }
    public object To { get; set; }
    public long? Count { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, this is not being mapped properly by hotchololate:

[image]

I have created a type and registered it like this:

```
public class FacetType: ObjectType<FacetModel>
{
}

public static void AddGraphQLServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddGraphQLServer()
        .AddType<FacetType>()
        .AddQueryType<Query>();
}
```

But if I look at the docs, it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what is happening with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the type of your properties are `object`. Hot Chocolate doesn't know how to handle `object`, since there's no concept of an `object` in GraphQL.
There's the object type, yes, but it has a known set of fields, which the `object` does not have - it could be anything.

That being said, there's an `AnyType` in Hot Chocolate. You could annotate your object as an `AnyType` and then retrieve the actual value in your resolvers.

```cs
public class FacetModel
{
    [GraphQLType(typeof(AnyType))]
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

The `AnyType` only works for scalars (string, int, ...) and `IDictionary` though. If these objects need to support different object types, I'd suggest using unions.

[Learn more about the AnyType](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/scalars/#any-type)

[Learn more about unions](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/unions)